# How to fix PHP error: Unable to get local issuer certificate?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, xampp, certificate

This is my environment setup:

```
Mac OS Sierra (10.12.2)
XAMPP 5.6.23
PHP 5.6.23
```

I'm using the PHP version that is included with XAMPP:

```
$ which php
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.23 (cli) (built: Jun 24 2016 09:25:00)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

This is my PHP code:

```
  $postData = array('FORM_DATA' => 'data');
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://testhub.banregio.com/adq',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_POST => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
  echo $response;
  echo $err;
  curl_close($curl);
```

I already added the following line to the `php.ini` file and, of course, downloaded the `cacert.pem` file from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem:

```
curl.cainfo=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/cacert.pem
```

My php.ini file is located in:

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

**Didn't work.** I can't set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false`.

Next, I added these options for `cURL` in the code above:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
CURLOPT_CAINFO => '/path/to/my/exported/certificate.crt'
```

The website has the following certificate:

[image]

Of course, I had to export it from **Keychain Access**:

[image]

**Keychain Access** can export `*.pem` and `*.cer` certificates. I tried with both. Actually, I renamed the `*.cer` certificate to `*.crt`.

**Didn't work either.**

Comment: This is usually a symptom of the server not providing its intermediate certificate in the TLS handshake.

Comment: Using Python Requests or even Postman works. Isn't that something related to PHP specifically?

Comment: Please confirm none of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate helped. It might help if you specify which ssl library you are using.

Comment: did you find a solution? Yes? what did yo do pls help

Answer (score -1):

On local you could simply disable SSL (please don't try this on production servers.)

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: I can't use these options.